# Istio virtual service not applying timeout

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I would like to use the **fault injection** mechanism of Istio.

*I have been task to add a timeout of 5 second on a service. So to achieve this I made my own virtual service which follows:*

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
  - hello-service.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - fault:
      delay:
        percent: 100   #Applies on all request
        fixedDelay: 5s #Timeout of 5 sec
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hello-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

As you can seen I only redirected the hello service on itself and applied the 5 second timeout. **Unfortunatly the timeout isn't working at all...**

---

This is the example from the [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-timeouts/):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ratings
spec:
  hosts:
  - ratings
  http:
  - fault:
      delay:
        percent: 100
        fixedDelay: 2s
    route:
    - destination:
        host: ratings
        subset: v1
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thx for your help

---

**Update 1 - Adding targeted service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9080
```

**Update 2 - Adding output of proxy-config**

```
$istioctl proxy-config route hello-75c874b67f-6l4p9
NOTE: This output only contains routes loaded via RDS.
NAME      VIRTUAL HOSTS
80        6
3000      4
8060      1
8080      2
8088      1
9090      1
9091      2
9093      5
9411      1
15004     2
15010     1
15030     1
15031     1
20001     1
          1
```

Comment: Could you please explain how do you test is it working or not?

Comment: @VAS Yep ! I simply request the hello service using curl  directly or from the browser. Each time, the server responds immediatly ! Even if I try to request through an existing pod the 5 second delay is not respected.

The only way I found to make it work is to put the timeout on the virtual service binding the gateway to a service. But here I'm interested to make it work from service to service.

Comment: Do you have the `DestinationRule` applied to your service?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Nope... As I only have one version of my app I didn't feel like deploying a destinationRule which I generaly use to bind multiple subsets of an application to  different deployments. Do you think I should I create a destinationRule with a single subset ?

Comment: @Doctor could you as well show you k8s Service configuration?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I updated the question with the service config as you asked. Its a really simple service. :-)

Comment: How do you curl the service? As from this configuration, you cannot access it directly outside the cluster

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I either curl using the ip of the service or through an other pod that makes the request from there (from inside the mesh in other word)

Comment: Seems odd. Can you run `istioctl proxy-config route <pod_name>` and see if there is `fixed_delay` in the configuration present?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Excellent idear ! I updated the question with the output. I must say that its not what I was expecting.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have to add `-o=json` to see the whole configuration

Comment: The output will be quite big, so try to grep it

Comment: @SergiiBishyr `istioctl proxy-config route hello-75c874b67f-6l4p9 -o json |grep "fixed_delay"` doesn't find anything unfortunatly... I guess that the created virtualService doesn't affect the targeted service for some reason.

Comment: That is strange. When to configuration is applied correctly this property should be present in the routing configuration. Do you apply the config using `kubectl` or `istioctl`?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I use kubectl but I've just tried with istioctl and did not changed anything.

Comment: This mean that this is not the validation issue. Can you confirm that the response is from the same service that you expect?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Yep ! The response is from the right service.

Comment: @Doctor this is definitely not the issue with the `VirtualService`, as I have applied the exact your configuration and the timeout is works. Somehow it is not applied to the proxy of your service.

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Wow.. What is your version of Istio if I may ask ? Thx for having test my virtualService !

Comment: It’s 1.0.3. However I don’t think it’s related to version here. Somehow it’s applied not to the service you are expecting it to. Try to share some more k8s configs if it’s possible

Comment: @SergiiBishyr You were right ! The virtual service works ! I did a test on a simple application and the timeout was applied... Then I used the same virtualService back on my original application and its still NOT working. Moreover I checked the defective app with the `istioctl proxy-config` tool and It HAS the `fixed_delay` in it's configuration this time... So its really really strange. Unfortunatly I run out of time on this task and must go on with something else for the time being :-(. I'll post an answer to explain what I achieved with your help and let it be for now.

Comment: I hope that I can fix it in the near future. Still, thanks a lot for your help and time ! :-)

Comment: One more suggestion to help you with debugging this issue: try to user kiali for visualization and validation of your istio configs. Here is the link: github.com/kiali/kiali

Answer (score 0):

**Adding this answer to give insight on the status of the issue.**

With the help of [@Sergii Bishyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5604676/sergii-bishyr) I now know that the virtualService provided in my question is working.

I tested it with 2 simple applications curling from the first one to the second one. In this case the timeout is applied !

Unfortunatly on the original app where I was using the virtual service its still not working.

The ***test applications*** and the **original one** are both webservers so I'm not sure why in one case its working and not in the second one... The mystery is not yet solved.